# javafx weird font on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, javafx, fonts

i've created this javafx application. It looks cool on linux and windows. But when i run it on Mac OSX it looks like this.

[image]

the problem is with font spacing and the font size also doesn't seem normal. I was using custom fonts in the app and i thought thats the cause of the font problem but after removing the custom font styles the problem doesn't seem to go away.

Comment: did you end up solving this

Comment: not actually. but it doesn't occur on new projects. i guess its because im using custom fonts.(ttf files)

Comment: hahaha, your comment actually just solved my problem, i realised the font was not installed in my OS X system, however the font is included in the jar and arabic showing on a debian system without font install

Comment: yet now i have another issue when the text is large!! needs another question i guess

Comment: glad to be of help :)

Comment: Have the same issues on JFX11, but I'm not using any custom font file. I guess this is likely a host problem